# how to rotate textureView to show a cameraPreview

Tags: android, android-camera, android-textureview

I use the camera2 api to show a camerapreview, and i lock the screen orientation on lanscape, my problem is that i want to rotate the textureview to display the correct camerapreview, when i rotate it using the method setRotation, it becomes smaller. I search on stack but all solutions are relative to camera(first api) so is there a solution to rotate the textureView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a rotation to the TextureView's matrix.  For an example, see [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "play movie activity", which sends the output of a video decoder to a TextureView (same basic principles as Camera preview).

If you look at [`adjustAspectRatio()`](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java#L211) you can see it adjusting the position (translation) and scale of the output to match the video's aspect ratio.  There's also a commented out `postRotate()` call that would rotate the output 10 degrees.

Note this is rotating the video frame within the View, not the View itself.

Comment: i did as you said, adding a new function the same as yours, i added this line so to rotate the textureView as you said: myMatrix.postRotate(90), but the textureView disappear, and on the info log i had this  message : " only received metering rectangles with wieght 0"

Comment: i call this method from the method onsurfaceavailable as i lock the screen orientation.

Comment: Start with a smaller rotation. Depending on how your matrix is set up you may be rotating it completely out of the view.